# Set the default video player from the command line

Tags: command-line, video, default-programs

I would like to set the default video player from the command line. Taking `xvideos` as an example, I tried replacing all references to Totem by `xvideos` in the `defaults.list` file:

```
mv /usr/share/applications/defaults.list /usr/share/applications/defaults.list.old.totem
sed 's/Totem/xvideos/' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list.old.totem > /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

The contents of this file now look like:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep xvideos
application/vnd.rn-realmedia=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
application/x-extension-m4a=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
application/x-extension-mp4=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
application/x-matroska=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
application/x-shockwave-flash=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/3gpp=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/ac3=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/AMR=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/AMR-WB=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/basic=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/midi=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/mp4=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/mpeg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/mpegurl=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/prs.sid=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/vnd.rn-realaudio=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-ape=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-gsm=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-it=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-m4a=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-matroska=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-mod=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-ms-asf=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-ms-asx=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-ms-wax=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-ms-wma=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-musepack=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-aiff=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-au=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-realaudio=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-wav=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-pn-windows-acm=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-realaudio=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-real-audio=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-sbc=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-speex=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-tta=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-wav=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-wavpack=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
audio/x-xm=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
image/vnd.rn-realpix=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
misc/ultravox=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/3gpp=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/dv=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/fli=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/flv=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/mp2t=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/mp4=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/mp4v-es=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/mpeg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/msvideo=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/ogg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/quicktime=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/vivo=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/vnd.divx=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/vnd.rn-realvideo=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/vnd.vivo=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/webm=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-anim=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-avi=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-flc=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-fli=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-flic=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-flv=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-m4v=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-matroska=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-mpeg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-asf=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-asx=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-msvideo=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-wm=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-wmv=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-wmx=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ms-wvx=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-nsv=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-ogm+ogg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-theora+ogg=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
video/x-totem-stream=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
x-content/video-dvd=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
x-content/video-vcd=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
x-content/video-svcd=org.gnome.xvideos.desktop
```

However, videos are still being opened with Totem by default, say, if I double click on a movie file in the file manager.

How else can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After about an hour of messing around with this I got this working for me, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1, I don't have `xvideos` I have vlc installed, so you can try simply substituting `vlc` for your player of choice.
Heres the command I run at a prompt

```
% sed -n '
1i[Default Applications]
/^video/{
s/Totem/vlc/
s/org\.gnome\.//p
}' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list > ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

running the above command produces

```
% cat ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
[Default Applications]
video/3gpp=vlc.desktop
video/dv=vlc.desktop
video/fli=vlc.desktop
video/flv=vlc.desktop
video/mp2t=vlc.desktop
video/mp4=vlc.desktop
video/mp4v-es=vlc.desktop
video/mpeg=vlc.desktop
video/msvideo=vlc.desktop
video/ogg=vlc.desktop
video/quicktime=vlc.desktop
video/vivo=vlc.desktop
video/vnd.divx=vlc.desktop
video/vnd.rn-realvideo=vlc.desktop
video/vnd.vivo=vlc.desktop
video/webm=vlc.desktop
video/x-anim=vlc.desktop
video/x-avi=vlc.desktop
video/x-flc=vlc.desktop
video/x-fli=vlc.desktop
video/x-flic=vlc.desktop
video/x-flv=vlc.desktop
video/x-m4v=vlc.desktop
video/x-matroska=vlc.desktop
video/x-mpeg=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-asf=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-asx=vlc.desktop
video/x-msvideo=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-wm=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-wmv=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-wmx=vlc.desktop
video/x-ms-wvx=vlc.desktop
video/x-nsv=vlc.desktop
video/x-ogm+ogg=vlc.desktop
video/x-theora+ogg=vlc.desktop
video/x-totem-stream=vlc.desktop
```

Now going to nautilus and double clicking a `mp4` file it is launched in `vlc`. I didn't need to hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or logout, it seems `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` is read on every invocation.

reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41196/106525

Comment: It seems it is all about setting the `defaults.list` file in the right place.

Comment: Changing with xdg-mime automatically writes the entry in that file.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa for me - it  was all about applying the section heading `[Default Applications]` into the beginning of the declaration block. It didn't work until I did that.

Comment: I just copied the `defaults.list` file I created in the question into `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` and it immediately started working.

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal, First grab all the reference of totem.desktop in a variable and then iterate the variable to set default. For example, if your desired applications .desktop file is `xvideo.desktop`, Go to `/usr/share/applications/` do these in terminal

```
videos="$(cat defaults.list | grep Totem.desktop | cut -d '=' -f 1)"
for i in "$videos"; do xdg-mime default xvideo.desktop "$i"; done
```

Don't forget to refresh your desktop by pressing `F5`, though may not required.  If it still doesn't seem to have changed log out of the system and the log in again.

Comment: well there it is ^_^

Comment: This answer looks good, but does not do it yet. I even logged out and back in, but Totem remains in control of all video file types.

Comment: try removing the `mimeinfo.cache` file in ~/.local/share/applications directory

Answer (score 2):

As of Ubuntu 18.04, when you change a default application in Settings or change a file association in Files, it gets stored in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. To change all video files from Totem to VLC in the same way as the GUI does, you can use:

```
sed -n '1p; s/org\.gnome\.Totem\.desktop/vlc\.desktop/p' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list > ~/.config/mimeapps.list
sed '1s/\[Default Applications\]/\n\[Added Associations\]/; 2,$s/$/;/' ~/.config/mimeapps.list >> ~/.config/mimeapps.list
```